# is it possible to encode list of objects in python to use it in compress function?

Tags: python, list, compression, encode, zlib

i have a large list and I want to compress it in python using zlib.compress function and decompress it in javascript,  in order to compress it, it must be encoded in utf-8, my question is: is it possible to encode it? if not, how I can compress this list in python and decompress it in angular?

list example:
[{"name":"value1","y":0.0}, {"name":"value2","y":1.0} , .. ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first need to encode the list into a sequence of bytes that could be interpreted at the other end. [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html) might be a good choice in this case, depending on if the list content is suitably constrained. Then use zlib to compress the sequence of bytes.

Comment: Inside zlib.compress() it should be bytes not a string so the JSON encode didn't work for me
When encode is done, many characters become missing and are scribbled on the other side(javascript)

Comment: That's why I said a sequence of bytes. Use `.encode()` on the string to convert it.